# Why TabbarView crash when swipe to next tabarView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollbar, flutter-listview

> on changing tabbarView I'm getting this error
>
> > package:scrollable_positioned_list/src/scrollable_positioned_list.dart':
> > Failed assertion: line 250 pos 12: '_scrollableListState == null': is
> > not true.

```
>  here is running code examlpe ..just call this class from main.dart
```

> use this package in yaml scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.2.3

I cant find any solution .. I dont have any idea why its crashing when I'm changing tabbar

```
class ExamleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
          final int  index; 
          ExamleScreen({Key key,@required this.index}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override 
          State<ExamleScreen> createState() => _CategoriesSubScreenState();
        }
        
        class _CategoriesSubScreenState extends State<ExamleScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
               int currentIndex =0;
               TabController _tabController;
               ItemScrollController itemScrollController;
               ItemPositionsListener itemPositionsListener;
               int index = 0;
        
        // @override
        //   bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
        
          @override
            void initState() {
              super.initState();
              index = widget.index;
            
               itemPositionsListener = ItemPositionsListener.create();
               itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
              WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) { 
                itemPositionsListener.itemPositions.addListener((){
                  
                  final visibleIndex =itemPositionsListener.itemPositions.value;
                      currentIndex = visibleIndex.last.index;
                  print(visibleIndex.last.index);
                  setState(() {
                    
                  });
                
                 });
        
              });
        
              _tabController = TabController(length: 10, vsync: this);
              _tabController.animateTo(widget.index);
              _tabController.addListener((){
                currentIndex = 0;
                print('my index is'+ _tabController.index.toString());
                index = _tabController.index;
               setState(() {});
              });
        
            }
          @override
              void dispose() {
                _tabController.dispose();
                
                super.dispose();
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              //  super.build(context);
            return MaterialApp(
                  home: DefaultTabController(
                  length: 10,
                  child: Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      bottom: TabBar(
                        controller: _tabController,
                        labelColor: Colors.white,
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                        overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                            return Colors.blue;
                          } if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
                            return Colors.orange;
                          } else if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                            return Colors.pinkAccent;
                          }
          
                          return Colors.transparent;
                        }),
                        indicatorWeight: 3,
                        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                        isScrollable: true,
                        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        onTap: (int index) {
                          print('Tab $index is tapped');
                        },
                        enableFeedback: true,
                        tabs:  [
                         for (int  i =0 ;i< 10; i++ )
                               Tab(child:Text("Example name"))
                         ],
                      ),
                      title: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                          SizedBox(width: 12,),
                          const Text('Categories'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    body:
                     Column(
                      children: [
                      Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            height:50,
                            child:ListView.builder(
                                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: 6,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemBuilder: (context,index1){
                              return Container(child:  Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: ()async{
                                      scrollTo(index1);
                                      currentIndex = index1;
                                      setState(() {
                                        
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      color:currentIndex == index1 ? Colors.blue:Colors.white,
                                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                                    child: Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                      child: Center(child:  Text("sub Category name",style: TextStyle(color:currentIndex == index1 ?Colors.white:Colors.black,),
                                                     )
                                                    ),
                                                   )
                                                  ),
                                  ),
                              )
                              );
                            }) ),
                          
                      Expanded(
                          child: TabBarView(
                            controller: _tabController,
                            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            children: [
                                   for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++ )
                                   
                                       ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                                                itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
                                                itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
                                                itemCount:6,
                                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                                      return  Column(
                                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                            children: [
                                                        
                                                              Padding(
                                                               padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16,right: 16,top:4,bottom:4),
                                                                child: Container(
                                                                    width: 170,
                                                                    child: Text(
                                                                      "sub Category name",
                                                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                                      maxLines: 2,
                                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                                        color:Colors.black,
                                                                      ),
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ),
                                                              ),
                                                              ListView.builder(
                                                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                                                  physics:ScrollPhysics(),
                                                                  itemCount: 4,
                                                                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                                                  itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
                                                                            return GestureDetector(
                                                                              onTap: (){},
                                                                              child: CategoryItemWidget());
                                                                }
                                                              )
                                                              ]
                                                         );
                                                        
                                                },
                                              )
                                             
                               ]
                          ),
                        ),
                     
                      ],
                    
                    )
                  ),
                ),
              );
          }
          void scrollTo(int index){
                  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) { 
            if(itemScrollController.isAttached){
              itemScrollController.scrollTo(
              index: index,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
              );
          
            }
                  });
          }
        }
        
        class CategoryItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
          const CategoryItemWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16,right: 16,top:4,bottom:4),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          height: 150,
                          width: 300,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                                  spreadRadius: 1,
                                  blurRadius: 3,
                                  offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                                ),
                              ],
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              // Column(
                              //   children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                          "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FUQmCz6XoAINzeQ.jpg:large",
                                          height: 120,
                                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                          width: 130),
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                width: 170,
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "Peak Frech Biscuits with choclate",
                                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  maxLines: 2,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Rs 40",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              //   ],
                              // ),
                              Positioned(
                                bottom: 10,
                                right: 6,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 30,
                                  width: 120,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                      color: Colors.blue,),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(Icons.horizontal_rule_rounded,color: Colors.white),
                                      Text(
                                        "1",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
          }
        }
```

Comment: are you using null-safety?

Comment: You have too much load in isolated thared , even I m not able to execute your code, also please try to make a common function for widgets and business logic..so your code may well organize

Comment: i'm not using null safety

Comment: you have any idea how can I achive withiut using null safety